# Copy data to file in matrix format

Tags: java

I have a loop which returns 4 values every time:

```
rowValue, columnValue, x, y.
```

I want to copy these values to a file in below format:

```
            columnValue1 columnValue2 . . . columnValueN
rowValue1       x,y         x,y        . .      x,y
rowValue2       x,y         x,y        . .      x,y
.                .           .          ..       .
.                .           .          ..       .
.
rowValueN
```

I want to map x,y values at intersection of column and row values.
x,y values are of type `Double` and are random.

Please let me know how to do this? or if there is a java library available?

Comment: Do you get the values in defined order (eg. from *x1,y1*, through *x1,y2*, **x1,y3*, ..., *x1,yN*, .., *xM,yN*)?

Comment: based on rowValue and columnValue, x and y values are calculated. They are of type Double and are random. I also edited my question.

Comment: Are you know at least how many rows and columns is?

Comment: No. I get that data from a webservice

Comment: I think you have to store data in array and create method which stores this array in file. And after each adding value you have to clean file and write it again. Or, if you don't need to update file in real time, you can store data in array and write it all to file at the end. It's hard (I think) to update file and keep it well formated

Comment: Could the columns have gaps in a row? e.g. one row `{rowValue1, columnValue1, x1, y1} and {rowValue1, columnValue2, x2, y2}` another row `{rowValue2, columnValue1, x3, y3} and {rowValue2, columnValue3, x4, y4}`. Or all matrix points are filled?

Comment: Why not use an existing format for spreadsheets, like CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Following sketch might be a solution for your requirement.

- store the loop values in a map `Map<rowValue, Map<columnValue, Double[]>>`, keep a set of `columnValues`
- output of the `columnValues` in the first line
- iterate over all entries of map `Map<rowValue, Map<columnValue, Double[]>>`

  - iterate over all stored `columnValues`
  - if the map `Map<columnValue, Double[]>` contains a value pair for a `columnValue`
    output the values 
    else output blanks

Here a small working code snippet (see it as a verbose PoC, not as a final solution suiteable for production use).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Object[][] input = { 
        {"rowValue1", "columnValue2", 33.33, 44.44},
        {"rowValue2", "columnValue1", 55.55, 66.66},
        {"rowValue1", "columnValue1", 11.11, 22.22},
        {"rowValue2", "columnValue3", 77.77, 88.88},
    };
    Map<String, Map<String, Double[]>> map = new TreeMap<>();

    Set<String> columnHeaders = new TreeSet<>();
    for (Object[] in : input) {
        String rowValue = (String) in[0];
        String columnValue = (String) in[1];
        columnHeaders.add(columnValue);
        Double xValue = (Double) in[2];
        Double yValue = (Double) in[3];
        if (map.containsKey(rowValue)) {
            Map<String, Double[]> rowMap = map.get(rowValue);
            rowMap.put(columnValue, new Double[] { xValue, yValue });
        } else {
            Map<String, Double[]> rowMap = new TreeMap<>();
            rowMap.put(columnValue, new Double[] { xValue, yValue });
            map.put(rowValue, rowMap);
        }
    }

    System.out.print("            ");
    for (String header : columnHeaders) {
        System.out.printf("%s  ", header);
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Double[]>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.printf("%-12s", entry.getKey());
        Map<String, Double[]> rowMap = entry.getValue();
        for (String header : columnHeaders) {
            if (rowMap.containsKey(header)) {
                Double[] columnValue = rowMap.get(header);
                System.out.printf("%s, %s  ", columnValue[0], columnValue[1]);
            } else {
                System.out.print("              ");
            }
        }
            System.out.println("");
    }
}
```